# AndEngine ResolutionPolicy with GenyMotion

Tags: android, andengine

I have the following code:

```
public static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 1080;
public static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 1920;

public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        EngineOptions op = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,
                new FillResolutionPolicy(), mCamera);
        return op;
    }
```

I am also adding a sprite of 256x256 dimensions.

But when I run this code on GenyMotion emulator with Samsung S5, I get the image stretched.
I also tried to use the RatioResolutionPolicy but it require that I switch the order of width/height in its arguments because of Landscape option, which I don't think it makes sense.

Any ideas why stretching is happening?

thanks

Comment: Genymotion might be stretching the image. I assume you're using a web cam?

Comment: No, the image comes from the assets.